# How much time does it take for the bitcoin-qt window to show up in OS X 10.4?

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac

I have downloaded Bitcoin-Qt for Mac yesterday. I understand that it takes a while to "synchronise" but this site says one can access it whilst this process takes place. I have the Bitcoin in my applications folder but when I click on the icon nothing happens. A friend says he could monitor the progress of the synch, I can't see anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What verison of the client are you installing? what version of OSX you running? Does the application load into memory? Im not familiar with debugging OSX but im sure these details will help someone else.

Comment: To closevoters--this seems like a valuable question to have on the site, though it might be able to use an edit.  The criteria for "too localised" is that a question is "unlikely to help any future visitors" and it seems perfectly reasonable that there will be OSX 10.4 visitors for a while yet.

Comment: Editted to include the most pertinent element--OS X version.

Answer (score 2):

When you open the Mac client, it first displays the loading screen for a while :

[image]

After that it displays the main screen and starts synchronizing :

[image]

Note that the client is *really* slow and might take a while to load. If it's still not displaying the loading screen after a minute, try opening it again. As far as I know the Mac client doesn't have any requirements for installation.

To diagnose the issue, please perform these steps :

- Go to Activity Monitor (it's in the Utilities folder) and see if Bitcoin-qt is running. It should be.
- Open Console (also in Utilities) and see if there are any errors about Bitcoin-qt.
- Restart your Mac. It may help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Botcoin does not appear in the Activity Mon or the Console, so I downloaded again from Sourceforge (bitcoin-0.8.1-macoscx). My Downloads folder opens showing the orange "Bitcoin" icon and my Applications folder. I then drag the former into the latter. When I click on the icon nothing happens, I haven't seen the wallet image you show. My Mac is Intel OSX v10.4.11. Sorry if I sound dumb, I'm not very computer savvy. John

Comment: Ah, well, that explains it then. The earliest supported version of Mac OS X is 10.5. Either update your Mac, buy a new one, or use a different wallet.